# How do I keep Chrome from caching my js file that I'm trying to debug?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, caching

I am facing an issue that is driving me insane. I have one and only one js file called template2.js in my js folder. I keep overwritting this file when I make modifications to my script. I am saving the file properly, but when I am testing my "pages" in the browser, I see in the Chrome debuger that an older version of that js file is taken into account. And that older version does not exist anymore as I have overwritten it. Hope someone can help me understanding what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache? And how do you know it's the older version, if you're over-writing with the same name each time?

Comment: This will sound crazy, but it works - I do it all the time.  Ctrl F5 is meant to do a full refresh, without using the cache, but it doesn't refresh some included files (mainly script files).  Hold Ctrl and press F5 3 or 4 times.  It forces it to do it correctly.  Crazy, but true.

Comment: Hello David. Thank you to take time to try help me out. I quit the browser and restarted it several times. I know it is an older version because as when I check "scripts" in the Chrome debugger, the content is not the same of the actual file content.

Comment: try CTRL+F5 to refresh cache from web. Another tip is to add a queryatring variable to your javascript file. ex: template2.js?v=<YourAssemblyVersionHere> ore another variable..

Comment: Hello Archer. Thanks for the tip. I am using mac. Do you know the key combination for mac?

Comment: Going to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and clearing the cache by hand will guarantee that it's been cleared.

Comment: Send out headers that tell chrome not to cache anything.

Comment: I clicked on the refreshed button as suggested and it works! Thank you guys for the help :)

Comment: ctrl+shift+del -> enter -> F5

Comment: Hello RedX how to set header to tell the browser not to cache anything?

Comment: header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

Comment: a real bad way I fix this with my css files is to add `http://site.com/some.css?<?php echo time();?>`. You could try it with the script tag's src...But it's a really bad way to do it.

Comment: Looks like this is (give or take) a dupe -- pretty good discussion (and answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11786277/1028230  The CacheKiller extension sounds like money if it works as advertised.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you open chrome developer toolbar, there's a cog-icon on the bottom right corner. Clicking that should open a black panel. That panel has a "Disable cache" checkbox under network-tab.

Other option would be to manually go clear the cache from preferences -> under the hood -> clear browsing data.

If you do more development using chrome, I'd just disable the cache. Saves a lot of time lost wondering about why things don't work and realizing it's the cache that didn't refresh properly.

Comment: Now you'll find it under the "Network conditions" tab — also at the bottom of the developer panel, next to the "Console" tab. If it's not there, click "..." icon to show that tab.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browser you are using, you can load a page without cache by holding certain keys. See this answer on SuperUser for the correct combos: https://superuser.com/questions/278553/does-holding-down-ctrl-shift-while-clicking-refresh-actually-have-an-effect-in-m